# How do I use Placeholders in Perl to Inject a Variable into Mysql

Tags: perl

I keep getting errors when attempting to use placeholders in my perl script for a Mysql routine.

Code :

```
use DBI;
my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "database";
my $user = "exxxxxx";
my $password = "xxxxx";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database;mysql_local_infile=ON";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$password);

$dbh->do("SET \@tempc5 = (SELECT temp FROM day5 WHERE time = '00:00') ");

my $inter1 = i24;

$sth = $dbh->prepare( "SET \@sumadd5 = (SELECT ? FROM humid WHERE temp=\@tempc5) " );
$sth->bind_param( 1, $inter1 );
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

This produces the following error:

```
Global symbol "$sth" requires explicit...
```

If I add a `my $sth` I get the following error:

```
Scalar found where operator expected...
```

Note that I am have no objection in trying this with `$dbh->do("SET"`
if possible.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot semi-colon after `my $sth;`?

Comment: To be clear, the solution to your problem is to declare `my $sth`. Since it did not help, you did something wrong. You are not showing the code that went wrong, so we cannot help you.

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the error you claim it does.

Comment: Sorry when I was removing comment I accidentally removed one line of syntax.  I updated the code above.  NOTE: the variable inter1 is actually generated by a calculation which produces the value "24" with "i" joined to it.

Comment: Leaving aside the syntax error, some issues with your code: 1) You create a statement handle but never execute it, so your second SQL statement is never actually run. 2) You try to set a MySQL session variable `@sumadd5`, but don't do anything with it. Since it's a session variable, it will cease to exist as soon as you call `$dbh->disconnect();`. 3) You call `$sth->finish();` explicitly. You should almost never call `finish` directly, and it serves no purpose here. What are you trying to do by calling it?

Answer (score 1):

The placeholders are not allowed for column names according to MySQL Manual for [`mysql_stmt_prepare()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-prepare.html) which is the function behind `prepare`.

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
>   example, they are permitted in the VALUES() list of an INSERT
>   statement (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison
>   with a column in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.
>   However, they are not permitted for identifiers (such as table or
>   column names), or to specify both operands of a binary operator such
>   as the = equal sign. The latter restriction is necessary because it
>   would be impossible to determine the parameter type. In general,
>   parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML)
>   statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

If you think about it, it would not make sense to prepare a statement where you can change a column. Preparation of statement includes execution plan, but you can't plan execution of a statement where you don't know if given column has or doesn't have an index on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a placeholder there.

When you call `prepare`, all structural information about your tables is baked into the query, waiting for you to pass in data values to replace placeholders when you `execute` the query.

But you're trying to use a placeholder for a column name, which is part of the table's structure.

If you fix the Perl syntax to be:

```
my $inter1 = 'i24';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SET \@sumadd5 = (SELECT ? FROM humid WHERE temp=\@tempc5) " );
$sth->execute($inter1);
```

it should run, but the `?` will be treated as a *data value* rather than a column name (structural information).  So you'll get the results of the SQL query

```
SET @sumadd5 = (SELECT 'i24' FROM humid WHERE temp=@tempc5)
```

instead of

```
SET @sumadd5 = (SELECT i24 FROM humid WHERE temp=@tempc5)
```

The subquery will return the literal value "i24" for each matching row rather than the value found in column `i24`.

Answer (score -3):

You didn't quoted the vaule of `$inter1`. Change `$inter1 = i24;` to `$inter1 = 'i24';`. Just edited in your code, this will not give you syntax error.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use DBI;
my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "database";
my $user = "exxxxxx";
my $password = "xxxxx";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database;mysql_local_infile=ON";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$password);

$dbh->do("SET \@tempc5 = (SELECT temp FROM day5 WHERE time = '00:00') ");

my $inter1 = 'i24';

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SET \@sumadd5 = (SELECT ? FROM humid WHERE temp=\@tempc5) " );
$sth->bind_param( 1, $inter1 );
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but the reason was probably that you only fixed syntax errors without any explanation.

Comment: In a good answer, you should also explain why there were syntax errors, what lines you changed and how the fixes work.

Comment: Thanks serenesat.  I have a question. I have a query that uses the result of the @sumadd5 variable [  dbh->do("UPDATE day5 SET sumadd= (SELECT \@sumadd5) WHERE time= '03:00:') ");  ] , do I have to include it int the $sth routine in order for it to pick up the variable result?

Comment: @BrianB : if it helped you. accept this as an answer so it can be closed as solved. And for any other/further problem you can post a new question.